# Switch/Case statements in awk issue

Tags: awk, switch-statement

I have have looked around and a lot of answers are kinda old and aren't helping.  First question) Is the switch statement default in awk now or does it still have to be compiled with it.
Second question) When using a switch statement I get a syntax error on the : after the case,
ex:
switch(thing) {
case "TY":<--says this is a syntax error but everything I've read says it's right.
case "other":
}
Any help/insight into switch/case statement in awk would be amazing.
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Switch-Statement.html

Comment: `awk --version`?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st Question :

No, it is not "default". 
The  `switch` statement is gnu awk specific feature.

#### 2nd Question :

For the syntax error, you should provide more codes.

Comment: Is there a simple way to check and if it's not enabled, turn it on?

Comment: @ace_ashford you should know which awk do you use, and its doc will tell you what feature does it have. If you want to test, this should print `OK` : `awk '{switch($1){ case "foo": print "OK" }}' <<<"foo" `